# How can the DOCTYPE be changed to force Quirks mode in CMSDesk in Kentico

Tags: doctype, quirks-mode, kentico

I am running Kentico v5.5.3996 R2 and there are some aspects of the CMSDesk admin screens that will not work unless it is running in IE Quirks mode.

It mostly affects the WYSIWYG editor and the pop-up windows for Insert Images or Media.

So what I would like to achieve is to force CMSDesk into Quirks mode so that the editors do not have to manually change to Quirks mode whenever they want to edit the site.

Comment: Is it possible if you could provide some information on what exactly isn't working? Possibly may have some suggestions for that. And any information such as the template engine you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it in the IIS server as its a element in the server if wanted on all pages. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

If you want to adjust in a single Doctype, you can use Kentico Macros to render the proper header. See: for examples: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Kentico Macros can be very useful. In the dev guide search for "macro expressions overview"

Answer (score 0):

To turn the CMS desk into quirks mode edit the following file /CMSMasterPages/UI/EmptyPage.master and remove the doctype. This should throw the cmsdesk into quirks mode.